# Need help about softwares for managing both php & mysql on Mac OS X

Tags: php, mysql, osx-lion, mamp, wampserver

I need help about softwares like MAMP, Wamp Server & ... to managing both php & mysql on mac os x. can u share me somthing like a list that will do this to me? it's to important for me cause i am switching from windows to mac for my develop & programming skills...

Best Regards.

Comment: [MAMP or MAMP Pro](http://www.mamp.info/) are pretty good ways to go for setting up a dev environment on a Mac. If you're having a specific configuration issue, you can contact their support. Otherwise, you'll have to be much more specific about what help you need and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You should seriously look into [Zend Server Community Edition](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/). It is amazing software that many PHP professionals use. It pairs with Zend Studio, which is a great IDE, and allows you to manage your HTTP server, MySQL and PHP config through the click of a few buttons.